# Не получается прописать обработчик событий для кнопки

Tags: java, android, firebase

Не могу добавить функцию добавления в избранное через list массив, вообще раньше делал через данные firebase, создавалась модель в нее заносились геттеры и сеттеры. Но сейчас не получается реализовать такой же способ. Мне необходимо на каждый продукт добавить кнопку "Добавить в избранное" эта кнопка по нажатию должна добавлять товар на новую активити OrdersPage, на ней расположен как раз таки лист, но он пуст. Ничего не могу с этим поделать. Очень сильно прошу содействия. **Ознакомьтесь с проектом пожалуйста на google disk** [тык тык](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Ghn3LNvVhlieJfAvLUT3IfWzeP-4QfD/view)

Orderpage активити, в которой выводится список добавленных элементов:

```
    package com.example.dpaper_shop;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import com.example.dpaper_shop.Model.MyObjectBox;
    import com.example.dpaper_shop.Model.Station;
    import com.example.dpaper_shop.Model.Station_;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    import io.objectbox.Box;
    import io.objectbox.BoxStore;
    
    
    public class OrderPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] stations = {"Station1","Station2","Station3","Station4","Station5","Station6","Station7","Station8","Station9"};
    BoxStore boxStore;
    Box<Station> stationsBox;
    StationAdapter adapter;
    Button buttonSelect;
    boolean onlyFavorite;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_page);


        boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(this).build();
        stationsBox = boxStore.boxFor(Station.class);

        if (stationsBox.getAll().isEmpty()) {
            // если база не заполнена, то заполняем данными
            for(String station:stations){
                stationsBox.put(new Station(station));
            }
        }

        buttonSelect = findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect);
        RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.list);

        buttonSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // переключаем отображение всего списка или только избранного
                onlyFavorite = !onlyFavorite;
                String textButton = onlyFavorite? "All Station": "Only favorite station";
                buttonSelect.setText(textButton);
                //обновляем список
                getDataset(onlyFavorite);
            }
        });

        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        ArrayList<Station> dataset = getDataset(onlyFavorite);
        adapter = new StationAdapter(dataset);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<Station> getDataset(boolean onlyFavorite) {
        // делаем выборку в БД. Показывать все станции или только избранные
        ArrayList<Station> dataset = (ArrayList<Station>) (onlyFavorite? stationsBox.query().equal(Station_.favorite, true).build().find(): stationsBox.getAll());
        //обновляем список
        if (adapter != null) adapter.notifyList(dataset);
        return dataset;
    }

    public void onClickFavorite(View view){
        // здесь обрабатываем клик на кнопке избранного в айтеме списка
        // метод вызывается по атрибуту android:onClick xml-разметки айтема

        // Получаем ID станции, на которой кликнули кнопку избранного
        long id = (long) view.getTag();
        // инвертируем отметку избранного
        Station station = stationsBox.get(id);
        station.setFavorite(!station.isFavorite());
        stationsBox.put(station);
        //обновляем список
        getDataset(onlyFavorite);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        boxStore.close();
    }
}
```

**разметка  OrderPage**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    tools:context=".OrderPage">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="362dp"
        android:layout_height="377dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSelect"

        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonSelect"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickFavorite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="Only favorite station" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**StationAdapter**

```
    package com.example.dpaper_shop;
    
    
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import com.example.dpaper_shop.Model.Station;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class StationAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<StationAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<Station> stations;

    public StationAdapter(ArrayList<Station> stations) {
        this.stations = stations;
    }

    @Override
    public StationAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_items_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StationAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Station station = stations.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(station.getName());
        // Надпись на кнопке избранного
        // Если не в избранном, то "добавить". Если в избранном, то "убрать"
        String buttonText = station.isFavorite()? "Delete favorite": "Add favorite";
        holder.buttonFavorite.setText(buttonText);
        // отправляем в активити ID станции, на которой нажали кнопку избранного
        holder.buttonFavorite.setTag(station.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stations.size();
    }

    public void notifyList(ArrayList<Station> stations){
        this.stations = stations;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView name;
        final Button buttonFavorite;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            buttonFavorite = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonFavorite);
        }
    }
}
```

**И модель бд Station**

```
    package com.example.dpaper_shop.Model;
    
    import io.objectbox.annotation.Entity;
    import io.objectbox.annotation.Id;

    @Entity
    public class Station {
    @Id
    long id;
    String Name;
    String url;
    boolean favorite;

    public Station() {
    }
    public Station(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {this.id = id;}
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public boolean isFavorite() {
        return favorite;
    }
    public void setFavorite(boolean favorite) {
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }
}
```